# "Exception handling" in shell scripts

Tags: shell, zsh

I know that you can use the shortcutting boolean operators in shell scripts to do some sort of exception handling like so:

```
my_first_command && my_second_command && my_third_command
```

But this quickly becomes unreadable and unmaintainable as the number of commands you want to chain grows. If I'm writing a script (or a shell function), is there a good way to have execution of the script or function halt on the first nonzero return code, without writing on one big line?

(I use `zsh`, so if there are answers that only work in `zsh` that's fine by me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-e` option does this:

```
   ERR_EXIT (-e, ksh: -e)
          If a command has a non-zero exit status, execute the ZERR  trap,
          if set, and exit.  This is disabled while running initialization
          scripts.
```

You should be able to put this on the shebang line, like:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh -e
```

Most shells have this option, and it's usually called `-e`.

Comment: This is perfect -- thanks so much! I'll accept as soon as the no-accept-window expires.